# Referencing Variable to Root Directory in .kv File

Tags: python, kivy, nuitka

So I've got a single .py file and .kv file I'm compiling via Nuitka, plus images. They're all in the root directory with each other. After being compiled into an exe, the images don't load (for the backgrounds and buttons and such). I confirmed they only load if a variable is declared in Python, like so:

```
_local_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

And in Python the image is referred to like this: `bg = PhotoImage(file=_local_dir + /"bg_select.png")`

Problem is...while that works for any functions that reference images in the .py file, most of the images are referenced in the .kv file since that builds the layout itself. So how can the .kv file reference the local dir when .kv can't use variables?

## **Example from Python, where it does work after being compiled since it uses the _local_dir variable:**

```
_local_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

class MyApp(App):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(MyApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.current_user = os.getlogin()
        self.selected_items = []


    def securityPolicy(self):

        if "Configure Security Policies" in self.phase_1_features:
            win = Tk()
            bg = PhotoImage(file=_local_dir + "/bg_select.png")
            background = tkinterlabel(win, image=bg)
            background.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
            win.configure(bg='#0a1d32')
            win.geometry("350x190")
            win.title('Select Security Policy')
            win.resizable(0, 0)


    def build(self):

        return MyLayout()
```

## **Example from the .kv file (works in PyCharm, doesn't show up after being compiled)**

```
<MyLayout>
    BoxLayout:
        background_color: (33/255,98/255,166/255,1)
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding: 25
        size: root.width, root.height
        spacing: 10
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: root.width, root.height
                source:'box_bg.png'
```

So in short, I need to somehow have the .kv file reference the local directory in the same way as the .py file. Or in at least Kivy's way of telling it to go to the root.

Comment: Why don't you just do `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__FILE__))`?  Now the working directory is the one with your file, and you can open files without a path.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.resources.html#kivy.resources.resource_add_path to add the assets folder path. And then use `myimage.png` without referencing the folder (assets) or any kind of variables.